# Google Maps V3.3

Tags: java, google-maps

I am trying to build a quick application with Java/Hibernate that uses Google Maps heavily. I have narrowed to the following:

1. Ext JS with JSP
2. RichFaces
3. HTML / JQuery with Play Framework

I would appreciate some input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Google Maps javascript library you will be using AJAX a lot. So choose a framework that handles this well.

My personal favorite would be (out of the ones presented) HTML+jQuery with Play REST+JSON backend.